# how to append the data in existing MySQL table where table name matches using pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have a zip of excel files of one day data and written the code to unzip files and store in new folder,
by using pandas data frame I want to convert all excel files in to MySQL tables until here my code is working correctly and stores all my excel files data into MySQL tables and assigning excel file names as MySQL table names,
next day same zipped files are there I want to append in to existing database table where the table name last 5 digit number which is IMEI number matches then only it has to append new data how to do this so far i tried this code

```
import os
import zipfile

import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

zip_file_path = r"C:\Users\Aparns\Downloads\01-10-2023_-1684286926.zip"
output_directory = r"C:\Users\Aparns\Downloads\01-10-2023_-1684286926"

with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(output_directory)

extracted_files = os.listdir(output_directory)

db_config = {
    "host": "localhost",
    "user": "root",
    "password": "root",
    "database": "mydb"
}

db_connection = mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)
cursor = db_connection.cursor()
mysql_engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://root:root@localhost/mydb")

for file_name in os.listdir(output_directory):
    if file_name.endswith('.xlsx'):
        filename = "".join(file_name.split("_")[:-1])
        print(filename)
        table_name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0][:60]
        print(table_name)
        table_name = (
            table_name.replace(" ", "")
            .replace("-", "")
            .replace("+", "_")
            .replace("_", "")
            .replace("(", "_")
            .replace(")", "")
            .replace(".", "")
        )
        print(table_name)

        excel_file_path = os.path.join(output_directory, file_name)

        try:
            # Specify column names here (adjust as needed)
            column_names = ['Vehicle', 'Date', 'Time', 'IGN', 'Battery %', 'External Voltage', "Location", "Speed",
                            "Last Distance (meters)", "Distance", "History Data", "No Of Satellite", "Coordinates"]
            df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path, skiprows=5, names=column_names)
            df["date_time"] = df["Date"] + " " + df["Time"]
            df.drop(columns=["Date", "Time"], inplace=True)

            df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
            df = df[['Vehicle', 'date_time', 'IGN', 'Battery %', 'External Voltage', 'Location', 'Speed',
                     'Last Distance (meters)', 'Distance', 'History Data', 'No Of Satellite', 'Coordinates']]
            if pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'], errors='coerce').notna().any():
                df.to_sql(table_name, mysql_engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
                print(f"Data from {file_name} has been stored in the {table_name} table.")
            else:
                print(f"Skipping {file_name} due to missing or invalid date values.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error processing {file_name}: {str(e)}")
if the 15 digit IMEI number in the table name matches with current file name IMEI number then only it has to append the data
```